# How to add random term in different steps of numerical integration

Tags: c++, numerical-integration

For the function below, I would not add the noise (`Inoise` in the code below) in every time step but, for example, only in every second time step. So while `dt=0.0025` serves as the time step for the numerical integration, I would, for example, add `Inoise` only in every second time step (i.e. in 0.005 steps).

What is the best way to insert this into my existing function?

```
    runs = 1000;
    t_end = 5;
    dt = 0.0025;
    t_steps = t_end/dt;

    for(int j=0; j<runs; j++){

        double vT = v0;
        double mT = m0;
        double hT = h0;
        double nT = n0;

        for(int i=0; i<t_steps; i++){

            double IStim = 0.0;
            if ((delay / dt <= (double)i) && ((double)i <= (delay + duration) / dt))
               IStim = I;

            mT = (mT + dt * alphaM(vT)) / (1.0 + dt * (alphaM(vT) + betaM(vT)));
            hT = (hT + dt * alphaH(vT)) / (1.0 + dt * (alphaH(vT) + betaH(vT)));
            nT = (nT + dt * alphaN(vT)) / (1.0 + dt * (alphaN(vT) + betaN(vT)));

            const double iNa = gNa * pow(mT, 3.0) * hT * (vT - vNa);
            const double iK = gK * pow(nT, 4.0) * (vT - vK);
            const double iL = gL * (vT-vL);
            const double Inoise =  (doubleRand() * knoise * sqrt(gNa * A));
            const double IIon = ((iNa + iK + iL) * A) + Inoise;

            vT += ((-IIon + IStim) / C) * dt;
            voltage[i] = vT;

            if(vT > 60.0) {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accumulate the elapsed time and only add the noise once enough steps have passed:

```
double elapsedTime = 0;
double INoiseThreshold = 0.005;

for(int j=0; j<runs; j++){

    //...

    for(int i=0; i<t_steps; i++){

        //...

        double Inoise = 0;
        elapsedTime += dt;

        if(elapsedTime >= INoiseThreshold){
            Inoise = (doubleRand() * knoise * sqrt(gNa * A));
            elapsedTime = 0;
        }
        const double IIon = ((iNa + iK + iL) * A) + Inoise;

        //...
    }
}
return count;
```

- Instead of comparing the floating point numbers directly, you could check if their differences are within an small epsilon to allow for rounding errors.
- Instead of making the value of Inoise dependent on the condition, you could make the presence in the IIon formula dependent e.g.:

  ```
  const double IIon = ((iNa + iK + iL) * A) + (elapsedTime >= INoiseThreshold) ? Inoise : 0;
  ```

  just remember to reset elapsedTime once it surpassed the threshold.